# Are Cross Domain Flash Local Shared Objects (LSO aka Flash Cookie) possible

Tags: javascript, flash, cookies, cross-domain, lso

I found several solutions for creating Flash LSOs from JavaScript (for example: http://www.nuff-respec.com/technology/cross-browser-cookies-with-flash )
If Page (www.hostA.com/index.html) and the .swf file are from the same site, everything works fine.

No I'm trying to load the page form www.hostA.com/index.html, which includes www.hostB.com/flashcookie.swf (different sites). But then I cannot read or store the LSO.

I have tried several configurations (crossdomain.xml,  Security.allowDomain("...") ), but nothing works.

Is this kind of cross domain access to a LSO possible?

Can a flash based advertisement delivered by a 3rd party save a LSO on my disc?

Thanks
 -stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most useful information is here:
http://magp.ie/2010/10/15/javascript-library-to-manage-flash-local-stored-objects/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible, at least at adobe docs they say you can't:

> You cannot access shared objects
>   across sandbox boundaries.

Comment: I read that too, i think if I embed the .swf, it should be possible to set a LSO for the embedding domain, in the example, for www.hostB.com, this should be inside the sandbox.

For example, can the youtube player store a LSO on my computer, if i watch a embedded video in a blog?

Comment: Can a flash based advertisement delivered by a 3rd party save a LSO on my disc?